# Actionscript 3 - Max. 3 sockets from one client?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, sockets, tcp

I was trying to write a stress tester for my own protocol when I stumbled up on this problem.

Anytime I create more than **4** connections from **one** PC Flash denies to receive anymore messages from the server although I'm still able to **connect**, and **write messages**.

Could this have anything to do with the [flash policy file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/cross_domain_policy.html)? Or does this have something to do with security issues?

Comment: I would assume that Flash in the browser has a limit to the number of open connections it can make.  If you're waiting for info back, that is an open connection.

Comment: If I open the application in the stand-alone Flash executable the same problem occurs.

Comment: How do you create a stand alone Flash executable?

Comment: How about an error code or just some code in general?

Comment: @The_asMAn: I will try to get some code online tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using? I'm taking a guess at IE.  All internet communication goes through the browser Flash is currently running on (if in exec mode, goes through the OS' browser).  Therefore, the max connection is based on the settings of the browser.  I believe IE 6 had a limit of 2.  This might of gone up over the years.  There is a way to increase the limit, but I don't remember it offhand.  If you're using Firefox, I believe the limit is 10.

Now, what I don't understand in all this is *why* you're using Flash as a stress tester.  Flash is front end language, not something to use for testing.  If you want to do it properly, use Java or C# or anything else that isn't entirely view based and single threaded...

Comment: Do you know about the `NetConnection` class? I've managed to get a 1000 connections with that. The browser didn't matter. And I've used Firefox, Opera, IE8 and Google Chrome. It doesn't matter which browser I use. I keep getting the same results.

Comment: So long as the protocol is not http based, you should be fine, but still, you won't be stress testing much with a single threaded language. More on max connections:  http://deceptiveresolution.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-netconnections-available-to-a-swf-running-in-a-browser/

Comment: So, Flash's socket actually goes through the browser even though I'm not using port 80? While the NetConnection doesn't?

Comment: That's not what I said.  Any transfer protocol that is http based goes through the browser (http requests, remote object calls, RTMPT, etc).  Any other kind of transfer protocol are not.  What are you doing with NetConnection exactly?  There's a good chance you're using RTMPT or RTMFPT (which is http based).

Comment: The stress tester I made with the NetConnection class was using the RTMP protocol which uses port 1935.